# Two dropdown, show second dropdown based on first dropdown selection using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Data i m getting from the api.

```
{
  "Result": [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "DeliveryDate": "2020-11-06T10:11:07.5990202+08:00",
      "WeekDay": "Today",
      "IsEnabled": true,
      "TimeOptionList": [
        {
          "Id": "1",
          "DeliveryCollectionTime": "08:00 AM-10:00 AM",
          "IsEnabled": false
        },
        {
          "Id": "2",
          "DeliveryCollectionTime": "10:00 AM-12:00 PM",
          "IsEnabled": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Id": 2,
      "DeliveryDate": "2020-11-07T10:11:07.5990219+08:00",
      "WeekDay": "Saturday",
      "IsEnabled": true,
      "TimeOptionList": [
        {
          "Id": "1",
          "DeliveryCollectionTime": "08:00 AM-10:00 AM",
          "IsEnabled": true
        },
        {
          "Id": "2",
          "DeliveryCollectionTime": "10:00 AM-12:00 PM",
          "IsEnabled": false
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

> From the fist dropdown need to show the 'weekDay' and second dropdown 'DeliveryCollectionTime'

```
// state and onchange functions
  let [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(null)
  let [selectedTime, setSelectedTime] = useState(null)
  const getSelectedDate = (event: any) => {
    setSelectedDate(selectedDate = event)
    console.log(selectedDate)
  }
  const getSelectedTime = (value: any) => {
    setSelectedTime(selectedTime = value)
    console.log(selectedTime)
  }
```

frist dropdown

```
<Row className='my-3'>
     <Col span={24} className="mb-1">
          <Select style={{ width: "100%" }} optionLabelProp={"value"} 
           defaultValue={'Select Collection Date'} onChange={getSelectedDate}>
               {deliveryOptions.Result.map((date, i) => (
                    <Option key={i} value={date.WeekDay} name={i} disabled={!date.IsEnabled ? 
                    'disabled' : ''}>
                        {date.WeekDay}
                    </Option>
                ))}
          </Select>
    </Col>

// second dropdown

    <Col span={24}>
          <Select style={{ width: "100%" }} optionLabelProp="value" 
           defaultValue={'Select Collection Time'} onChange={getSelectedTime}>
                {deliveryOptions.Result[0].TimeOptionList.map((timing) => (
                     <Option key={timing.Id} value={timing.DeliveryCollectionTime} 
                      disabled= {!timing.IsEnabled ? 'disabled' : ''}>
                                    {timing.DeliveryCollectionTime}
                     </Option>
                ))}
          </Select>
    </Col>
</Row>
```

how to show the second dropdown timeoptionlist according to the weekday selected from the first.
Finally need to get the value of selected - DeliveryDate and DeliveryOptionTime

Answer (score 0):

```
  let [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(0)
  let [selectedTime, setSelectedTime] = useState(null)
  const getSelectedDate = (event: any) => {
    setSelectedDate(selectedDate = event)
    console.log(selectedDate)
  }
  const getSelectedTime = (value: any) => {
    setSelectedTime(selectedTime = value)
    console.log(selectedTime)
  }
```

and

```
<Row className='my-3'>
     <Col span={24} className="mb-1">
          <Select style={{ width: "100%" }} optionLabelProp={"value"} 
          defaultValue={'Select Collection Date'} onChange={getSelectedDate}>
                {deliveryOptions.Result.map((date, i) => (
                     <Option key={i} value={i} name={i} disabled= 
                          {!date.IsEnabled ? true : false}> {date.WeekDay}
                     </Option>
                ))}
          </Select>
      </Col>
      <Col span={24}>
           <Select style={{ width: "100%" }} optionLabelProp="value" defaultValue= 
           {'Select Collection Time'} onChange={getSelectedTime}>
           {deliveryOptions.Result[(selectedDate === null) ? 0 : 
           selectedDate].TimeOptionList.map((timing) => (
                <Option key={timing.Id} value={timing.DeliveryCollectionTime} 
                disabled={!timing.IsEnabled ? true : false}>
                      {timing.DeliveryCollectionTime}
                </Option>
            ))}
            </Select>
      </Col>
</Row>
```

Now i m able to show second dropdown value according to the first and also able to disable the option from the api(data)

But, How to get the selected - DeliveryDate and DeliveryOptionTime

becoz i used first dropdown key as a value of it so i m not getting - DeliveryDate
for second i m able to get the value of DeliveryOptionTime